# Returning objects from array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

Given the following code:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name    
  @@people = []

  def initialize(first_name,last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @@people.push(self)
  end

  def self.search(last_name)
    @last_name = last_name #accept a `last_name` parameter
    @@people.select { |person| person.last_name }
    #return a collection of matching instances
  end

  #have a `to_s` method to return a formatted string of the person's name
  def to_s
    #return a formatted string as `first_name(space)last_name`
  end
end

p1 = Person.new("John", "Smith")
p2 = Person.new("John", "Doe")
p3 = Person.new("Jane", "Smith")
p4 = Person.new("Cool", "Dude")

puts Person.search("Smith")

# Should print out
# => John Smith
# => Jane Smith
```

What do I need to do to return the output under the `Should print out` bit? I can get it to return the object id:

```
#<Person:0x007fa40c04cd08>
#<Person:0x007fa40c04c920>
#<Person:0x007fa40c04c5d8>
#<Person:0x007fa40c04c5b0>
```

One problem that I see with that without even knowing what is in each one: there should only be two values returned. So clearly the search portion is also wrong.

What should I be doing with this?

Comment: You should implement `Person#to_s` to do what the comment says - *"# return a formatted string as first_name(space)last_name"* - then iterate over what `Person#search` returns and call `Person#to_s` on each object.

Comment: Also your search method is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Person
      attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
      @@people = []

      def initialize(first_name,last_name)
       @first_name = first_name
       @last_name = last_name
       @@people.push(self)
      end

      def self.search(last_name)
       @@people.select { |person| person.last_name == last_name }
       #return a collection of matching instances
      end

      #have a `to_s` method to return a formatted string of the persons name
      def to_s
        "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
      end
    end

    p1 = Person.new("John", "Smith")
    p2 = Person.new("John", "Doe")
    p3 = Person.new("Jane", "Smith")
    p4 = Person.new("Cool", "Dude")

    puts Person.search("Smith").collect(&:to_s)
```

I have changed the self.search method to select the objects that have the same last name and obviously the to_s method + what gets puts out. Have a read test and let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks. I see that, aside from not doing anything with the `to_s` method just yet (I was waiting to figure out how to pare down to only the two expected return values first), I wasn't properly comparing `person.last_name` to `@last_name` in `self.search`. With that properly in place I am now only getting two objects returned. And now, the `to_s` method is doing what it should with the inserted code. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Add condition and maping array on @@Person. 
Code is described here:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name    
  @@people = []

  def initialize(first_name,last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @@people.push(self)
  end

  def self.search(last_name)
    @last_name = last_name #accept a `last_name` parameter
     @people = @@people.select { |person|  person.last_name == @last_name }.map{|p| p.first_name.to_s + ' ' + p.last_name.to_s}

    #return a collection of matching instances
  end

  #have a `to_s` method to return a formatted string of the person's name
  def to_s
    #return a formatted string as `first_name(space)last_name`
  end
end

p1 = Person.new("John", "Smith")
p2 = Person.new("John", "Doe")
p3 = Person.new("Jane", "Smith")
p4 = Person.new("Cool", "Dude")

puts Person.search("Smith")
```